# Jquery Remove Generated Fields From Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that generates fields as needed when the user is inputting information.
I also have a function that loads userdata from a database into the form to be edited.
However some users have less data than other and extra fields get left behind when their data is loaded. I know I can use $(text).remove to get rid of the unwanted fields, but I don't know how I could go about selecting all but the first fields in each section?

This is on of the sections of the form I need to remove everything but the first Background_Text and Background_Rank fields.

```
<tr class="end_background">
    <td class="col1">
        Background 1:
    </td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input class="background_text_1" name="background_text_1" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="end_background">
    <td class="col1">
        Background 1:
    </td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input class="background_text_1" name="background_text_1" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col1">Background Rank 2:</td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input class="background_rank_2  spinner" name="background_rank_2" type="number" value="2">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="end_background">
    <td class="col1">Background 2:</td>
    <td class="col2"><input class="background_text_2" name="background_text_2" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="col1">Background Rank 3:</td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input class="background_rank_3  spinner" name="background_rank_3" type="number" value="3">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="end_background">
    <td class="col1">Background 3:</td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input class="background_text_3" name="background_text_3" type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you change the code that generates the new fields? If so, you can add a class, for example `[some prefix]-generated`, and then use `$(".[some prefix]-generated").remove();` or something like that. The prefix is because some js libraries also use a class `generated` to indicate dynamically generated html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
$('input[name^="background_text"]').each(function (i) {
    if (i != 0) $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('input[name^="background_rank_"]').each(function (i) {
    if (i != 0) $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/5udtC/5598/)

Comment: beginning exactly with a given string. [more info](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)